# How can I find the value of an unnamed JSON object? (org.json) (java)

Tags: java, json, maven, org.json

[Java 17 using the org.json parsing library. Not able to switch to Gson because I've written an insane amount of code in org.json :/ ]

Hello!
I am using an API in Java with the org.json JSON parsing library. I need to get the value of an unnamed JSON object in an array.

```
{
  "lorem": [
   { // this object needs to be retrieved
     "ipsum":"dolor",
     "sit":"amet",
     "consectetur":"adipiscing"
   },
   { // this object also needs to be retrieved
     "ipsum":"dolor",
     "sit":"amet",
     "consectetur":"adipiscing"
   },
   { // this object needs to be retrieved
     "ipsum":"dolor",
     "sit":"amet",
     "consectetur":"adipiscing"
   }
  ]
}
```

Note that the entire JSON file is NOT an array, there is just one JSON array inside of a JSON object. How would I be able to get the value of all of these unnamed fields inside of the array?

Thanks in advance for any help, and also sorry if this question has been asked before, I wasn't able to find anything on it when I searched for it on Stackoverflow.

Comment: What code have you tried? What problem are you having? By the way, I don't see any unnamed fields.

Comment: no code has been tried, as there is no clear way to get this field. the unnamed OBJECTS are inside of the array. All of the JSON objects inside of the "lorem" array are unnamed, if that's the correct way to phrase it. the fields "ipsum":"dolor" are the fields inside of the unnamed objects. Basically, those curly brackets in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those objects aren't really unnamed objects, they are part of an JSON array. Because they are contained in an array, we can iterate through that array and we can retrieve every object by index.

Assuming that the we read the json provided above from a file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String resourceName = "src/main/resources/input.json";
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(resourceName);

    JSONTokener jsonTokener = new JSONTokener(inputStream);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonTokener);

    // Get the array named lorem from the main object
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("lorem");

    // Iterate through the array and get every element by index
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println("ipsum:" + object.get("ipsum"));
        System.out.println("sit:" + object.get("sit"));
        System.out.println("consectetur:" + object.get("consectetur"));
    }
}
```

Also, `JSONObject`  has a `toList` method, which returns a `List<Object>`.

Comment: thanks! ill add another comment after i try this, as im currently on a phone

Comment: Are you finished your phone call?